# Number of maximal independent sets in a hypergraph

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, enumerative-combinatorics

Are there any known upper bounds on the number of maximal independent sets in a hypergraph? I'm aware that simple graphs have an upper bound of $O(3^{n/3})$. How about on the number of independent sets?

Comment: You might have some info in David Conlon's lecture 14, taking about Moon-moser inequality for hypergraph, due to Caen (alas I can't access Caen paper) http://www.its.caltech.edu/~dconlon/Extremal-course.html

Comment: @ThomasLesgourgues Thanks for the link!

Comment: @bof That is exactly what I wanted. Maybe you can provide an argument for the upper bound on the number of maximal independent sets as an answer?

Comment: @bof The hypergraphs that I need to consider are not necessarily $r$-uniform, for any fixed $r$, so I needed a bound on the general case. However, I would be interested to here also about the uniform case, if you have any nice references on that.

Comment: OK, I posted my comment as an answer. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't misunderstanding the question. I don't know about the uniform case, no doubt it's more difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The family of maximal independent sets of a hypergraph has the property that no member of the family is contained in another. Such a family of sets is called an *antichain* or a *clutter* or a *Sperner family*. By [Sperner's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sperner%27s_theorem), a Sperner family of subsets of an $n$-element set has at most $\binom n{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}$ members. In particular, a hypergraph $H=(V,E)$ of order $|V|=n$ has at most $\binom n{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}$ maximal independent sets. This bound is attained when $E$ is the set of all $\left(\lfloor n/2\rfloor+1\right)$-element subsets of $V$.